# Sql query select sum of table1 and sum of table2 and subtract them

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Select idn, sum(tblppmp.total_item) as a_total
sum(tblRequest.Quantity) as b_total
sum(a_total- b_total) as itemsleft
FROM PPMP.dbo.tblppmp, ppmp.dbo.tblrequest
Group by idn
```

i have my problem how to sum individual items from table1 and table2 and the result will be subtracted to get the answer.

like this

```
table1
id     item
1        2
2        3
3        4
```

table2

```
id       item
1        1
2        2
3        3
```

the result i want is like this..

table 3

sum(table.item) - sum(table2.item)

```
table1.id 1 = 2
table2.id 1 = 1
so (2-1) = 1

id     item_left
1      1
2      1
3      1
```

id        item

Comment: Not the answer but a couple of quick SQL tips... 1) remember to read your question & produce SQL accordingly - for example your field names are incorrect (itemsleft vs items_left). 2) use declared joins (e.g. FROM PPMP.dbo.tblppmp inner ppmp.dbo.tblrequest on ...) as this is much easier to read + maintain 3) spacing & case sensitive SQL is important for readability (e.g. all SQL should be in UPPERCASE, spaces should be used to keep SQL left aligned) etc 4) Use table alias (where does idn come from?)

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `sum(a_total- b_total)`. You have to use `sum(tblppmp.total_item) - sum(tblRequest.Quantity)`.

```
Select tblppmp.idn
, tblppmp.total_item as a_total 
,tblRequest.Quantity as b_total 
,tblppmp.total_item - tblRequest.Quantity as itemsleft 
FROM dbo.tblppmp 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT
tblrequest.idn
,sum(tblRequest.Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM tblrequest 
WHERE tblrequest.dr_year = 2015
GROUP BY tblrequest.idn) tblrequest ON tblppmp.idn = tblrequest.idn
```

Comment: sir the problem is the sum(tblppmp.total_item) was multiplied why?

Comment: Because a_total or b_total is alias, you can not use them.

Comment: Select tblppmp.idn, sum(tblppmp.total_item) as a_total
,sum(tblRequest.Quantity) as b_total
,sum(tblppmp.total_item) - sum(tblRequest.Quantity) as itemsleft
FROM PPMP.dbo.tblppmp
INNER JOIN ppmp.dbo.tblrequest ON tblppmp.idn = tblrequest.idn
where tblrequest.dr_year = 2015
Group by tblppmp.idn

Comment: Do you have any problem?

Comment: Select tblppmp.idn, sum(tblppmp.total_item) as a_total
,sum(tblRequest.Quantity) as b_total
,sum(tblppmp.total_item) - sum(tblRequest.Quantity) as itemsleft
FROM PPMP.dbo.tblppmp
INNER JOIN ppmp.dbo.tblrequest ON tblppmp.idn = tblrequest.idn
where tblrequest.dr_year = 2015
Group by tblppmp.idn '--------------with this code sir the total item was multiplied to the number items requested in table request sir

Comment: There are not any problem for your code. I think so.

Comment: unlike if  i used the this code..select sum(tblppmp.total_item) from tblppmp it gives me the correct answer but if i join the tablerequest, the sum was multiplied to the nuber of items requested.

Comment: For example, if tableA has 2 rows with id 1, and tableB has 3 rows with id 1. Then after `inner join` you have 6 rows, and your `sum` will be incorrect. That's problem.

Comment: the table a has only 1 row sir, it is constant because that was my main table, the tableB is my problem because it may change depending on the number of items requested. TableA 1 row, tableB 3 or 5 rows

Answer (score 0):

You could caculate sum for each table first and then subtract them.

```
select  idn, 
        a_total - ISNULL(r_total,0) as itemsleft
FROM
(
    select idn, sum(p.total_item) as p_total
    from    PPMP.dbo.tblppmp p
    group by idn
) p
LEFT JOIN 
(
    select idn, sum(r.Quantity) as r_total
    from    ppmp.dbo.tblrequest r
    group by idn
) r on p.idn = r.idn
```

Comment: thank you so much for your sir.. i love you.. i got it now!